# Messages.app on mac: search in history

Tags: macos, messages

i've a problem, i'm able to search for string in messages.app. It actually tells me all the matches for every conversation, the problem is that is shows only the last match, how can i go through all the results?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can simply use

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> in order to jump to the next occurrence

and

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> in order to jump to the previous one.

Comment: You're a godsend. Special thanks to Apple for applying the very least intuitive search key...

Comment: I would suggest an edit: remove 'simply' :p

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Spotlight Search?

Cmnd + Space

Make sure Messages is enabled for Spotlight Search in your Mac System Preferences.